# How to create dynamic web project in eclipse kepler?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How to create dynamic web project in eclipse kepler and is there any editor for jsp for eclipse kepler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you download the package that contains these tools. The one you want is labeled "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers". This package supports dynamic web projects and has an editor for jsp files.

Comment: If you're already running Kepler, you can also install both the Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools and JST Server Adapters Extensions from the Kepler Update Site.